# Bind each array element to option tag

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to bind an array element from a class to an option tag.

In the angular.io "Tour of Hero" tutorial ( https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html ) they do the following for a list :

```
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
```

If I understand it right the ***ngFor="let hero of heroes"** will associate each hero ( so each element in the heroes array ) to a li element and then display some caracteristics of the associated hero with {{hero.id}} for example.

I say associate because if it was just a simple loop with a print I don't see how they would get back the hero object after with onSelect(hero).

I have been trying to do the same with option :

```
   <option *ngFor="let perso of persos">
     <span>{{perso.id}} : </span> {{perso.nom}}
   </option>
```

But

```
(click)="onSelect(hero)"
```

isn't effective since then click event isn't triggered with option. I couldn't find the right trigger. Any help and additionnal information is very welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind a object to the `[value]` property of the `option` element.

I would bind the object's id to the `[value]` property of the `option` element and use the `(change)` event of the `select`.

See the example below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    Select your favorite serie:

    <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let serie of series" [value]="serie.id">{{ serie.name }}</option>
    </select>

    <br />
    <br />

    Selected Serie: <br />
    <span *ngIf="selectedSerie">
      {{ selectedSerie.id  }} - {{ selectedSerie.name }}
    </span>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  private series: any[];
  private selectedSerie: any;

  constructor() {
    this.series = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Friends' },
      { id: 2, name: 'How I met Your Mother' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Modenr Family' }
    ];

    this.selectedSerie = this.series[0];
  }

  onChange(serieId: any): void {
    this.selectedSerie = this.series.find(serie => serie.id == serieId);
  }
}
```

See the complete example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OOYx3LiN1pO3qffKn7lq

Answer (score 3):

For those native HTML elements Angular 2 offers two-way-bindings, so you can bind your values directly with `ngModel` - this works for all input tags. So if you change the selection manually, it also updates that variable with the current value. Also if you change `selectedPerso` programmatically, the view gets updated with the new selection.

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedPerso" (change)="onChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let perso of persos" [value]="perso.id">
        <span>{{perso.id}} : </span> {{perso.nom}}
    </option>
</select>
```

And in your component class body you define that binding variable with a default value which gets preselected on page load:

```ts
selectedPerso: number = persos[0].id;

onChange(event) {
    console.log("Selection changed: ", event);
}
```

Comment: Isn't [(ngModel)]="selectedPerso" and (change)="onChange($event)" redundant ?

Comment: It is, I assumed you wanted to execute some code on change.